# Where should I ask this question about CS quote?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

You have several computer science related sites, but I can't find one to ask a particular question.

I'm trying to source a computer science quote I remember before using it anywhere, so I go to https://cs.stackexchange.com, which seems like the most appropriate site based on the subject guidelines. I've tried searching the web, but I can't find it no matter how I search.

I put the tags, Unix and command, because the quote has to do with Unix commands. It tells me that neither tags exist, and I can find no other appropriate tags. Unix seems pretty fundamental not to have a tag, and I'm afraid to ask anywhere else. If I go to a non-computer science site nobody will know what I'm talking about, and if I go to a more specific computer science site my question will get closed for not having anything to do with coding.

Here is the question I would like to ask:

> Title: Who is the source of this CS quote?
>
> I was reading about Linux and Unix commands a while ago and someone who probably had a Masters or Doctorate Degree said something that's funny and memorable because it seems true. It was in response to someone asking him when he thought the last Unix commands would be entered, because Unix is very old. But Unix is one of those old things in the computing world that never goes out of style, so he responded something like this:
>
> > The last Unix commands will be entered shortly before the world ends, and they will probably have something to do with it.
>
> I've searched the web several different ways and couldn't find it, but I'd like to source this quote before using it.

Where should I ask this question?

Answer (score 2):

> Where should I ask this question?

It would seem that CS is not the best option as you already noticed, as they focus more on the CS part and less on the quotes and identification. If this was something you read, and are trying to identify the quote, perhaps you should **consider asking it on [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/)**.

I found they have a specific tag named [quote-identification](/questions/tagged/quote-identification), whose [description](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/quote-identification/info) reads:

> For questions looking to **identify the source of a quote.**

IMO this seems the best option I've found so far.

---

You could also consider asking on History.SE, as they also have a [quotes](/questions/tagged/quotes) tag, whose [description](https://history.stackexchange.com/tags/quotes/info) reads:

> This tag should be used for questions about someone's words and its context, reasons, **origin**, authenticity or purpose. It can also be used for the motives behind use of somebody's words by somebody else, e.g. "why did Smith quote Jones?"

In any case, make sure to take the tour on those sites, read their help pages, and look around so your post get good reception.

---

Yet another possible target (thanks to @curiousdannii) for your question could be [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/), where they also have a [quote](/questions/tagged/quote) tag. There is [no description](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quote) on this one, but looking for posts with that tag reveals questions asking for quote identification (like [Who did say that anyone who discover a new particle should be fined instead of receiving a prize?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/7563)).

Comment: Like I said in the description though, if I take this outside of a forum of computer geeks, nobody is going to know what it is.

Comment: @dboggs95 we don't know that for sure. I think you are *assuming* no one will get it, but if there is a Site that specifically searches for quote origins I'd say it's for any kind of quote. Besides, people on LIT can also belong to other sites, like SO... Never underestimate the manifold interests of us geeks :)

Comment: There is also the [hsm.se] site which would allow questions about quotes on computer science, but the quote the OP wants to ask about is a quip, not something actually about computer science.

Comment: @curiousdannii seems they also hace a quote tag. Thanks for the suggestion, including it on my answer :)